# Error in getting HTTP response custom Header

Tags: asp.net, http, http-headers, webforms

I am trying to add a custom Headers -> e1 `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("e1","example of an exception");` to HTTP response in Page_Load method which works fine as I checked it in chrome developer tools.

[image: U+25BC]

The problem is if I am trying to write the same response using :        `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["ALL_HTTP"].ToString());`
it causes an *PlatformNotSupportedException : This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.*

So the main question is how to read the added response header given I am using the inbuilt VS development server?
And it would be great if you can suggest some articles or book to know about **properly** using HTTP headers and verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write that variable directly to the response then you can simply call this in your Page_Load. This will avoid the IIS integrated pipeline mode requirement.

```
Page.Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["ALL_HTTP"]);
```

For learning I would concentrate on learning about HTTP and REST.

- A fun primer on REST http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife
- HTTP: The Definitive Guide by David Gourley (solid book that will guide you from the simple HTTP protocol into more advanced concepts)
- HTTP 1.1 spec at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html (dry read by the authority)